# How can I return a default value for an attribute?

Tags: python, reflection, attributes, default, void

I have an object `myobject`, which might return `None`. If it returns `None`, it won't return an attribute `id`:

```
a = myobject.id
```

So when myobject is `None`, the stament above results in a `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

If `myobject` is None, then I want `a` to be equal to `None`. How do I avoid this exception in one line statement, such as:

```
a = default(myobject.id, None)
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You should use the [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) wrapper instead of directly retrieving the value of `id`.

```
a = getattr(myobject, 'id', None)
```

This is like saying "I would like to retrieve the attribute `id` from the object `myobject`, but if there is no attribute `id` inside the object `myobject`, then return `None` instead." But it does it efficiently.

Some objects also support the following form of `getattr` access:

```
a = myobject.getattr('id', None)
```

As per OP request, ['deep getattr'](http://pingfive.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/deep-getattr-python-function.html):

```
def deepgetattr(obj, attr):
    """Recurses through an attribute chain to get the ultimate value."""
    return reduce(getattr, attr.split('.'), obj)
# usage: 
print deepgetattr(universe, 'galaxy.solarsystem.planet.name')
```

Simple explanation:

[Reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is like an in-place recursive function. What it does in this case is start with the `obj` (universe) and then recursively get deeper for each attribute you try to access using `getattr`, so in your question it would be like this:

`a = getattr(getattr(myobject, 'id', None), 'number', None)`

Comment: +1, This is probably the best idea, don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Ha, Thanks, going to use your endorsement for shameless self promotion. :P

Comment: @Inbar Rose And what if I want to obtain the attribute of attribute in same way, like `a = myobject.id.number`?

Comment: How about getattr(myobject.id, "number", None)?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to use the ternary operator:

```
a = myobject.id if myobject is not None else None
```

The ternary operator returns the first expression if the middle value is true, otherwise it returns the latter expression.

Note that you could also do this in another way, using exceptions:

```
try:
    a = myobject.id
except AttributeError:
    a = None
```

This fits the Pythonic ideal that it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission - what is best will depend on the situation.

Comment: Does it evaluate fast? I have 30000 objects to do this check.

Comment: @alwbtc Try it and see. Check out the `timeit` module. If you think it is very likely a large proportion of values will be `None`, the first method will probably be faster, otherwise, use the second.

Comment: OK, None values are not much. So I will use the second method. But I also want the code consisting of one-liners. Don't you think one-line statements are better?

Comment: @alwbtc: No, readable code is better.

Comment: @alwbtc Something being on one-line means nothing, in fact, it's generally a *bad* sign as most things are too complex to push onto a single line. Go for readable, then performance, then concise.

Comment: @alwbtc [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14923509/1561176) provides a one-liner, which is readable, and efficient, and approved by Lattyware... :P take a look.

Answer (score 7):

in my object class you can put override

```
class Foo(object):
   def __getattribute__(self, name):
      if not name in self;
        return None;
      else:
        # Default behaviour
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Comment: Your code fails with `TypeError: argument of type 'Foo' is not iterable`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to solve the problem in the definition of the class of `myobject` (like in [Black Diamond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14923560/918015)) you can simply define `__getattr__` to return `None`:

```
class Myobject:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return None
```

This works because `__getattr__` is only called when trying to access an attribute that does not exist, whereas `__getattribute__` is always called first no matter the name of the attribute. (See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405617/918015).)

To try out:

```
myobject = Myobject()
print myobject.id 
myobject.id = 7
print myobject.id
```

Answer (score 3):

> Help on built-in function getattr in module builtins:
>
> ```
> getattr(...)
>     getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value
> ```
>
> Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to x.y.
>   When a default argument is given, it is returned when the attribute doesn't
>   exist; without it, an exception is raised in that case.

Following should work:

```
a = getattr(myobject, 'id', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    a = myobject.id
except AttributeError:
    a = None
```

Will also work and is clearer, IMO

Comment: I"m not python specialist, but in most of the languages I used to deal with, falling in the "except" statement has an additional cost that is non substantial. In a simple case like this one, I would recommend the "getattr" approch (assuming this is less costly). Can some of you tell some more about the getattr method ?

Comment: premature optimisation, good lad, premature optimisation

Comment: This isn't premature optimization. Using exceptions to handle normal behaviour is generally considered bad style.

Comment: Python's exceptions are not **that** costly and this is the way it is shown throughout the interpreter source.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=myobect.id if myobject else None
```