# Python List to access dict directly

Tags: python

I have a document like this:

```
>>> k = {'finance_pl':{'S':{'2008':45,'2009':34}}}
```

Normal way to access is:

```
>>> k['finance_pl']['S']
{'2008': 45, '2009': 34}
```

But, in my case the end user will give me input as `finance_pl.S`

I can split this and access the dictionary like this:

```
>>> doc_list = doc.split('.')
>>> k[doc_list[0]][doc_list[1]]
{'2008': 45, '2009': 34}
```

But, I don't want to do this, since the dictionary structure may change the and 
user can give something like this `finance_pl.new.S` instead of `k['finance_pl']['S']` or `k[doc_list[0]][doc_list[1]]`.

I need something to apply the users input directly (Ex: if input is `finance_pl.new.S`, I should be able to apply this `.split('.')` method to the users input and apply directly).

What is the elegant way to do that ?

Comment: Not sure whether I understood the question correctly, i.e. whether there's more to it, but I think you should look at this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12414821/1639625)

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923465/python-how-to-return-a-default-value/14923509#14923509) I think it will help you. Also, see [Jon's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17787473/1561176) Which is how I would have answered your question.

Comment: Yes, @tobias_k I need something like this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> k = {'finance_pl':{'S':{'2008':45,'2009':34}}}
>>> ui = 'finance_pl.S'
>>> def getter(adict, key):
...     return reduce(dict.get, key.split('.'), adict)
... 
>>> getter(k, ui)
{'2008': 45, '2009': 34}
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd simply loop over all the parts:

```
def getter(somedict, key):
    parts = key.split(".")
    for part in parts:
        somedict = somedict[part]
    return somedict
```

after which we have

```
>>> getter(k, "finance_pl.S")
{'2008': 45, '2009': 34}
```

or

```
>>> getter({"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}, "a")
{'b': {'c': 'd'}}
>>> getter({"a": {"b": {"c": "d"}}}, "a.b.c")
'd'
```

Comment: Thanks @DSM, easily understandable solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for something like:

```
k = {'finance_pl':{'S':{'2008':45,'2009':34}}}
print reduce(dict.__getitem__, 'finance_pl.S.2009'.split('.'), k)
# 34
```

If you're using Python 3.x, you'll need a `from functools import reduce` in there...

Answer (score 1):

```
userkey = 'finance_pl.new.S'
for key in userkey.split('.'):
    k = k[key]
# the final value of k is the one you want
```

So basically just iterate on every subkey and retrieve the inner dictionary until you're out of subkeys